# Why animating content does not work in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations, keyframe

Why does the following animation works in Chrome but not in Firefox?

HTML:

```html
<button>Loading</button>
```

CSS:

```css
button {
  width: 70px;
  text-align: left;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  animation: dots 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes dots {
  0% { content: ''; }
  25% { content: '.'; }
  50% { content: '..'; }
  75% { content: '...'; }
}
```

[Playground](http://jsbin.com/pazasopehe/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the specification does not allow for [`content` to be animated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

Comment: Thanks for the link. [This article](https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/) sheds more light on this.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the Chrome development strategy has devolved into more or less doing whatever they want instead of adhering to standards. Chrome is the new IE.